# Mont a volume in host directoy

Tags: macos, docker

I am running an application with a dockerfile that I made.

I run at first my image with this command:

```
docker run -it -p 8501:8501 99aa9d3b7cc1
```

Everything works fine, but I was expecting to see a file in a specific folder of my directory of the app, which is an expected behaviour. But running with docker, seems like the application cannot write in my host directory.
Then I tried to mount a volume with this command

```
docker 99aa9d3b7cc1:/output .
```

I got this error `docker: invalid reference format.`

Which is the right way to persist the data that the application generates?

Answer (score 2):

Use [docker bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

e.g.

```
-v "$(pwd)"/volume:/output
```

The files created in `/output` in the container will be accessible in the `volume` folder relative to where the docker command has been run.